# JMeter, assert number of integers in a list

Tags: jmeter

I have a service that creates a given number of integers based on how many integers the user requests.

Example:

User requests 3 integers, the response would be: [123,234,345]

Is there a way in Jmeter to assert that I received 3 integers in the Response Body?

Comment: How is your response formatted ?JSON/XML/HTML/Other? Can you show response example?

Comment: The response is exactly like this [123,234,345]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below approach:-

RegEx to fetch all integers. Total match count ==9
[image]

If total match count is 9 then pass else fail with JSR223 Assertion.
[image]

Hope this helps.